# i add custom filter to solve allow cross origin and still denied the angular send only option method and doesn't send get or post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, maven, jakarta-ee

i add filter on java and trying to send request but it still get same error  ::

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/CodeSnipping/registration/validate. A wildcard
>   '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when
>   the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

the browser send validate with request method (option)

**my controller**

```
package com.Controller.tmp;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity validate() {
        System.out.println("HEREEEEE");
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**My Filter**

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse) resp;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");

        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            com.Controller.tmp.SimpleCORSFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

**angular.js**

```
MainCtrl.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $cookieStore,AppService,CityRetriever) {

    var loginReqobject = {
        username : "ahmed",
        password : "ahmed"
    };

    var test = function(){
        var res1 = AppService.Test(loginReqobject);     
    }

    test();

});

MainCtrl.factory('AppService', function($http , base64) {
    var BasicUrl = "http://localhost:8080/CodeSnipping/registration/validate";
    return {

        Test : function(loginReqobject) {
            var loginRequest = {
                url: BasicUrl,
                method: 'get',
                withCredentials: true,
            };
            return $http(loginRequest).then(function(response){
                console.log("success " + response);
                return response;
            }, function(response){
                console.log("failed " + response);
                return response;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**i add config on angular**

```
// snippingConfig is the angular module 
    SnippingConfig.config(function($httpProvider){
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    });
```

the full header 
[image: response header from option request method]

Answer (score 0):

try to set a specific url:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000");
```

Comment: same problem send only option request method

Comment: @sngv could you post the exact headers returned by the sever?

Comment: then you maybe need to set also response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, origin, content-type, accept");

Comment: i add the header returned by the server on image

Comment: i add the  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, origin, content-type, accept"); and  same error

Comment: @sngv are you still getting "A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true"?

Comment: the error ( is Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/CodeSnipping/registration/validate. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.)

Comment: @sngv coudn't be the problem the @RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.GET) line in your controller? try to remove the method restriction or add Get and Options method at once.

Comment: i was using com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter and the code was working when i add my custom filter it get this error

Answer (score 0):

Angular **always** sends an OPTIONS request, because it's the standard way of obtaining cross domain headers.

So you need something that handles the OPTIONS request (I always use a method inside my controller).

I think you need some other headers. Check this list:

- **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** - initialized from the value of the  **Origin** request header.
- **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials** - always set to true.
- **Access-Control-Request-Headers** - initialized from values from the equivalent request header.
- **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** - the HTTP methods a transport supports (see TransportType enum).
  **Access-Control-Max-Age** - set to 31536000 (1 year).

I think you need Access-Control-Request-Headers with the same value as the same request header

Comment: it send option request and response is ok 200 but doesn't send post or get after option request

Comment: Mmm, this is very strange!! Is the chrome console printing anything?

Comment: chrome console print this XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/CodeSnipping/registration/validate. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Try returning the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin with a value equals the "Origin" header of each request.